# java variables for whole package

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and I do not know how to make it so that these two variables inside the if statements, that need to be updated each time.

```
public class Ex3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Here will display what pi is
    System.out.println("Pi in Netbeans Java is "+ Math.PI);

    //This will give how many numbers the for loops go up to
    int maxNum = 20;

    //This is for the subtraction parts of the equation
    for(int i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++){
        int subNum = 3;
        final double subCount = 1 - (1./(subNum + 4));
        subNum += 4;
    }
    for(int y = 1; y <= maxNum; y++){
        int addNum = 5;
        double addCount = 1 + (1./(addNum + 4));
        addNum += 4;
    }
}
double finalNum = subCount + addCount;
}
```

Comment: Jacob, if my answer helped you please consider to upvote and/or accept

Answer (score 0):

variables a re limited to the scope in which there are declared, so if you declare a variable in a `for` block, then you can only see them in the `for` block.

To overcome this declare the variables before you use then in the `main` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Here will display what pi is
  System.out.println("Pi in Netbeans Java is "+ Math.PI);

  //This will give how many numbers the for loops go up to
  int maxNum = 20;
  double subCount = 0.0;
  double addCount = 0.0;
  int subNum = 3;
  int addNum = 5;

//This is for the subtraction parts of the equation
  for(int i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++){
    subCount = 1 - (1./(subNum + 4));
    // maybe should be
    // subCount += 1 - (1./(subNum + 4));
    subNum += 4;
  }
  for(int y = 1; y <= maxNum; y++){
    addCount = 1 + (1./(addNum + 4));
    // maybe should be
    // addCount += 1 + (1./(addNum + 4));
    addNum += 4;
  }

  System.out.println ("the result is " + (subCount + addCount));
}
```

**Edit**

Not sure what your logic is supposed to do though

Comment: Going to try to get the for loops to create two variables, and when those two variables are added together, they will create what equals pi.